# How to organize and setup mirrored backup servers for Git repositories?

Tags: git

I am moving some svn repositories to Git. So, what I basically try to do is this:

- Setup one server with bare Git repositories from which I will pull and push to
- Setup a few backup servers for all of my repositories that are on the 1st server.

So, let's say i have a directory on my server, like: `$HOME/git/`, which has bare repositories. Eg:

```
~/git/project1.git
~/git/project2.git
~/git/project3.git
...
```

My backup servers may be mirrors to this server, or keep the backed up data in archives or whatever. I suppose I can do something like:

```
git clone --bare ssh://gitserver/~user/git/projectX.git
```

Or maybe:

```
$ cd ~/git/project1.git
$ git bundle create ~/gitbackup/project1.bdl --all
```

and then copy all bundles from all projects to my backup servers.
However, having a lot of projects either strategy would be a tedious task, so in each case I would need to make some scripts to automate the task.

I wonder how are you guys doing this? Maybe there is some better way to do it than what I considered already. Any tip would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you might be better info on serverfault.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general idea would be to:

- create bare repo on your backup server
- have [hooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) (probably a [post-receive hook](http://toroid.org/ams/etc/git-repository-mirrors)) on your main bare Git repository to automatically push whatever is received to the corresponding Git backup repo, either through [`git:` protocol or `ssh+git:` protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#_the_ssh_protocol).

There are other techniques [back in 2008](http://web.archive.org/web/20090518010102/http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/en/node/551), based on **[gibak](http://web.archive.org/web/20081219090018/http://eigenclass.org/hiki/gibak-backup-system-introduction)**, but the idea remains the same.

---

Example of a post-receive hook:

- [this one](http://gist.github.com/68811) from [Grant Limberg](http://github.com/glimberg):

```
    #!/bin/sh
    #
    # A hook script that is called after a successful
    # commit is made.
    #
    # Place this file in .git/hooks and chmod +x

    BRANCH=`git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'`
    git push origin $BRANCH
```

- [that one](http://www.stopdropandrew.com/2010/01/20/making-an-authoritative-git-repo-auto-push-to-github.html) (in ruby)

```
    #!/usr/bin/env ruby
    STDIN.read.split("\n").each do |line|
       oldrev, newrev, refname = line.split(' ')

       if refname.match(/^refs\/heads\/(.*)/)
         branch = $1

         `git push origin #{branch}`
       else
         puts "#{refname} was weird, not sure what to do."
       end
    end
```

Comment: this hook pushes just the one branch, which is current in the repository. In my case I needed to backup all existing branches, so it goes like this: `git push origin`, and no BRANCH variable.

Comment: @AndersMetnik With links between 8 and 10 years old, I am not surprised ;) Anyway, I have restored *all* links.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't seem like there's anything special here -- you just need a standard backup solution.

I've had good luck with rsnapshot, or rsync if I just need simple backups.