# Back up a git remote repositore with git hooks

Tags: git, backup, githooks, git-bash, git-workflow

I have some puzzle pieces and it would be great if someone could help to master the pieces together to have a whole picture.

I have a couple of devs who develop on several git repo's locally and push frequently to the matching remote repositories on the server.

Now I would like to replicate or automate a second backup on another server.

I learned that when I define a `post-receive` hook on my remote repository and include a `git push to my backup server` then I could automate it that way? Is this correct?

Now: I have the local and the first remote repo under control but not so much the backup repo. So if somebody starts a new git repo I could distribute the `post-receive hook` via `global git settings`. But is it possible that I can check in my `post-receive hook` if the back-up repo exists and if not `init` a new one and then `push`? And if it exists just `push` the current state to the backup. I found something like `git ls-remote` to query the remote but to not know how to handle it...

But like  said I am not sure how to write the `git post-receive hook` that it automatically re-pushes changes to the back-up server... and on top I have to use windows server for this =)

P.S.: I also saw something like `git bundle` but did not figure out how this could help me...
Anyway I'm just looking for an automated backup solution for my remote repo to a backup repo...

Comment: This is answered fairly well here: [mirrored backup servers for git][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284415/how-to-organize-and-setup-mirrored-backup-servers-for-git-repositories